# How can I sort it the way I want in the FlatList?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I would like to list the items(in card component) in order in which the number of values of 10 contents and 10 ingredients in the cookup match.

My final goal is to list the items in the Card component in the order of the number of matches of content and ingredient.

Cookup and ingredient range from 1 to 10, respectively.

```
      cookup:
      [
        0:{ name: "second" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "6" content5: "7" content6: "5" content7: "empty" content8: "10" content9: "8" content10: "9" }

        1:{name: "third" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "empty" content5: "5" content6: "empty" content7: "4" content8: "empty" content9: "6" content10: "empty"}

        2:{name: "four" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "empty" content5: "4" content6: "empty" content7: "empty" content8: "empty" content9: "empty" content10: "empty"}

        3:{name: "first" content1: "8" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "1" content5: "4" content6: "6" content7: "7" content8: "5" content9: "9" content10: "10"}

        4:{name: "fifth" content1: "empty" content2: "empty" content3: "3" content4: "1" content5: "empty" content6: "2" content7: "empty" content8: "empty" content9: "empty" content10: "empty"}
      ]
```

And ingredient has these values.

```
    ingredients1: 1
    ingredients2: 2
    ingredients3: 3
    ingredients4: 4
    ingredients5: 5
    ingredients6: 6
    ingredients7: 7
    ingredients8: 8
    ingredients9: 9
    ingredients10: 10
```

I would like to list the items in the order of the highest number of matching number of content and ingredient.

expected item value is that

```
    item: 

    {name: "first" content1: "8" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "1" content5: "4" content6: "6" content7: "7" content8: "5" content9: "9" content10: "10" }

    {name: "second" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "6" content5: "7" content6: "5" content7: "empty" content8: "10" content9: "8" content10: "9"}

    {name: "third" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "empty" content5: "5" content6: "empty" content7: "4" content8: "empty" content9: "6" content10: "empty" }

    {name: "four" content1: "1" content2: "2" content3: "3" content4: "empty" content5: "4" content6: "empty" content7: "empty" content8: "empty" content9: "empty" content10: "empty"}

    {name: "fifth" content1: "empty" content2: "empty" content3: "3" content4: "1" content5: "empty" content6: "2" content7: "empty" content8: "empty" content9: "empty" content10: "empty" }
```

How do I fix the code to do that?

this is my code

(Food.js)

```
    const Food = ({route}) => {
      const [lastId, setLastId] = useState(30);
      const {
        ingredients1,
        ingredients2,
        ingredients3,
        ingredients4,
        ingredients5,
        ingredients6,
        ingredients7,
        ingredients8,
        ingredients9,
        ingredients10,
      } = route.params; // Receiving Value
      const {cookUp, hasMorePosts, loadPostsLoading} = useSelector(
        (state) => state.post,
      );

      console.log('cookup:', cookUp);
      return (
        <>
          <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              console.log('ingredients1:', ingredients1),
              console.log('ingredients2:', ingredients2),
              console.log('ingredients3:', ingredients3),
              console.log('ingredients4:', ingredients4),
              console.log('ingredients5:', ingredients5),
              console.log('ingredients6:', ingredients6),
              console.log('ingredients7:', ingredients7),
              console.log('ingredients8:', ingredients8),
              console.log('ingredients9:', ingredients9),
              console.log('ingredients10:', ingredients10),
              (
                <ImageContainer>
                  <Card
                    item={item}
                    ingredients1={ingredients1}
                    ingredients2={ingredients2}
                    ingredients3={ingredients3}
                    ingredients4={ingredients4}
                    ingredients5={ingredients5}
                    ingredients6={ingredients6}
                    ingredients7={ingredients7}
                    ingredients8={ingredients8}
                    ingredients9={ingredients9}
                    ingredients10={ingredients10}
                  />
                </ImageContainer>
              )
            )}
          />
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Food;
```

(Card.js)

```
    const Card = ({item, ingredients1,ingredients2,ingredients3,
      ingredients4,ingredients5,ingredients6,
        ingredients7,ingredients8,ingredients9,ingredients10,
      }) => {

        console.log("item:",item);
        return (
        <>
        
          </>
        );
    };

    export default Card;
```

cookup type is like this when i console.log(cookup)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "I would like to list in the card component in the order in which the content **value of cookup and the ingredient value match the most**." Match how? Can you please edit your question to include a validly formatted object representation of `cookup` and `ingredients` and mockup what your expected "ordered" output would look like?

Comment: @HenryEcker
Sorry for the confusion what i mean is
I would like to list the items in the order of the highest number of matching number of content and ingredient. 

for example Ingredient contains values ​​from 1 to 10. ingredient1:1 to ingredient10:10..
In the cookup, the third array named first contains all values ​​of content from 1 to 10.
Therefore, it should be listed first.

Comment: Okay, follow-up question. What type is `cookout`? You have it with square braces(`[ ]`) like an array, but it has `0:` keys like an object?

Comment: @HenryEcker i just posted image in my post about cookup type.

Comment: Got it. I notice that cookup has 30 values, but your example only has 10 possible contents. Are there 30 content options in your actual `cookup` and you've just provided an abridged list? Or are there multiple elements in `cookup` that have the same number of filled content items? If so, how should elements be ordered that have the same amount of content?

Comment: @HenryEcker Cookup can be 10, 30, or 100. But the content value is only from 1 to 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231400/discussion-between-henry-ecker-and-user15322469).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure I understand what you are looking for. However, given my current understanding, you have an array called `cookout` which contains individual objects which are "fuller" or "emptier" based on the number of values in the object that contain either content or the word "empty".

You would like the list to be sorted with least "empty" first and most "full" last.

I create a "emptiness" tester:

```js
const emptiness = c => Object.values(c).filter(v => v === "empty").length;
```

Which takes an object and calculates the number of "empty" values in the Object.values.

I use this score to sort the array `cookout`:

```js
const sorted = cookup.sort((a, b) => emptiness(a) - emptiness(b));
```

```js
const cookup = [
    {
        content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", content4: "6", content5: "7",
        content6: "5", content7: "empty", content8: "10", content9: "8", content10: "9",
        name: "second"
    },
    {
        content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", content4: "empty",
        content5: "5", content6: "empty", content7: "4", content8: "empty",
        content9: "6", content10: "empty", name: "third"
    },
    {
        content1: "1", content2: "2", content3: "3", content4: "empty",
        content5: "4", content6: "empty", content7: "empty", content8: "empty",
        content9: "empty", content10: "empty", name: "four"
    },
    {
        content1: "8", content2: "2", content3: "3", content4: "1", content5: "4",
        content6: "6", content7: "7", content8: "5", content9: "9", content10: "10",
        name: "first"
    },
    {
        content1: "empty", content2: "empty", content3: "3", content4: "1",
        content5: "empty", content6: "2", content7: "empty", content8: "empty",
        content9: "empty", content10: "empty", name: "fifth"
    },
    {
        content1: "empty", content2: "empty", content3: "empty", content4: "1",
        content5: "empty", content6: "2", content7: "empty", content8: "empty",
        content9: "empty", content10: "empty", name: "sixth"
    }
];

const emptiness = c => Object.values(c).filter(v => v === "empty").length;
const sorted = cookup.sort((a, b) => emptiness(a) - emptiness(b));
console.log(sorted);
```

---

In your implementation this might look something like:

```
const Food = ({route}) => {
    const [lastId, setLastId] = useState(30);
    const {
        ingredients1,
        ingredients2,
        ingredients3,
        ingredients4,
        ingredients5,
        ingredients6,
        ingredients7,
        ingredients8,
        ingredients9,
        ingredients10,
    } = route.params; // Receiving Value
    const {cookUp, hasMorePosts, loadPostsLoading} = useSelector(
        (state) => state.post,
    );

    const emptiness = c => Object.values(c).filter(v => v === "empty").length;
    
    return (
        <>
            <FlatList
                data={cookUp.sort((a, b) => emptiness(a) - emptiness(b))}
```